# Find repeating values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find when the array has 2nd dimension values that are the same so I can deal with them.

I've looked at `array_unique` and other people who are asking a similar question, but they all delete the values instead of returning them.

Say I have an array like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [laps] => 7,
        [corrected_time] => 18
    ),
    [1] => array(
        [laps] => 6,
        [corrected_time] => 18
    ),
    [2] => array(
        [laps] => 7,
        [corrected_time] => 18.5
    )
)
```

I'd like to have it return: `array(0,1)` because they both have the same value for `corrected time`

Comment: wait. Is it only grabbed if `corrected_time` is repeated?

Comment: how about `array_unique` to remove duplicates, then `array_diff` to get the values removed?

Comment: @Jay Yes, sorry for not making this clear, I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach. First get the values for `corrected_time` and convert them to strings (because we'll use them in `array_count_values`, which only works on ints and strings).

```
$times = array_map('strval', array_column($your_array, 'corrected_time'));
```

Then find all the values that occur more than once using `array_count_values` and `array_filter`.

```
$repeats = array_filter(array_count_values($times), function($time) {
    return $time > 1;
});
```

After you have this list of repeated times, you can `use` it to filter your original array to only include items with repeated times.

```
$multiples = array_filter($your_array, function($item) use ($repeats){
    return isset($repeats[(string) $item['corrected_time']]);
});
```

You can iterate over this, or if you only want the keys, you can get them with

```
$keys = array_keys($multiples);
```

Comment: this seems a lot more complicated than the other answer

Comment: Have you tested the other answer with a larger set of values to see if it really does what you need it to? It appears to me that it only coincidentally works for the example from your question.

Comment: You are correct, I've done some tests and found the other answer doesn't complete the task suitably.